# Regex After Last / and Before period

Tags: php, regex

Sorry if the title is confusing. All I'm trying to do is some simple regex:

The text: `/thing/images/info.gif`

And what I want is: `info`

My regex (not fully working): `([^\/]+$)(.*?)(?=\.gif)`

(Note: `[^\/]+$` returns `info.gif`)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not `$result = pathinfo('/thing/images/info.gif', PATHINFO_FILENAME);`?

Comment: Cause I'm scraping a web page. But good idea under normal circumstances!

Comment: That seems to return only `t` from `thing`

Comment: I meant in place of the portion of yours not as the entire pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you don't need to match all the string, so you can be much more generic. If you know your string always contains a path you can just use:

```
preg_match( '/([^\/]+)\.\w+$/', "/thing/images/info.gif", $matches) ;
print_r( $matches );
```

and it will be valid for any filename, even names that contains dots like `my_file.name.jpg` or spaces like `/thing/images/my image.gif`

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/fJ5jZ1/1).

The structure is (from the end of the regex moving to the left):

- Match before the end of the string
- any number of characters preceded by a dot
- any character that is not a slash (your filename, if there is a slash, there starts the directories)

Comment: It works in regex101, but when I try in my code, it returns `info.gif`

Comment: Updated and tested. My output is `Array ( [0] => info.gif [1] => info ) `

Comment: Okay cool, so I'll just have to use the `[1]` portion of the return array. I like the more generic regex of this, it'll work the best. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much more complex the string is but this seems to work on the test string:

```
preg_match('![^/.]+(?=\.gif)!', '/thing/images/info.gif', $m);
```

Matching NOT `/` NOT `.` followed by `.gif`.

Comment: What I ended up with, which works: 
`$pattern = "/[^\/.]+(?=\.gif)/";`
`$strain_01 = preg_match($pattern, $filtered_text, $final_text);`
`return $final_text[0];`

Comment: Then you can't have multiple dots in the filename!

Answer (score 0):

In editors (Sublime):

Find:`^(.*)(\/)(.*)(\.)(.*)$`

Replace it with:`\3`

In PHP:

```
<?php

preg_match('/^(.*)(\/)(.*)(\.)(.*)$/', '/thing/images/info.gif', $match);
echo $match[3];
```